# Docusign API Not Sending Webhook Event Notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I can't seem to get Docusign API eventNotification webhooks to send.  When creating an envelope I've verified that the request is sending the correct eventNotification JSON hash that the API is expecting, both on my end and via the Docusign request log.  There are no connect logs, even though I specify that loggingEnabled is true, so I can't get meaningful feedback.  I've tried setting requireAcknowledgment to true as mentioned in another answer, as well as many other setting combinations.  I've read through the documentation extensively and many similar questions on SO, and none of the suggestions have worked for me.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

For starters, is there a way that I can verify, on the Docusign side, that the event notifications have actually been created from the request?

Here is the envelope creation request JSON

```
{
   "emailBlurb":"Please sign this proforma invoice.",
   "emailSubject":"Proforma Invoice",
   "documents":[
      {
         "documentId":"1",
         "name":"proforma_invoice.pdf"
      }
   ],
   "recipients":{
      "signers":[
         {
            "accessCode":"",
            "addAccessCodeToEmail":false,
            "customFields":null,
            "idCheckConfigurationName":null,
            "idCheckInformationInput":null,
            "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration":false,
            "note":null,
            "phoneAuthentication":null,
            "recipientAttachment":null,
            "requireIdLookup":null,
            "roleName":"Customer",
            "routingOrder":1,
            "socialAuthentications":null,
            "recipientId":1,
            "email":"john@smith.com",
            "name":"John Smith",
            "autoNavigation":false,
            "defaultRecipient":false,
            "signatureInfo":null,
            "tabs":{
               "approveTabs":null,
               "checkboxTabs":[

               ],
               "companyTabs":null,
               "dateSignedTabs":[
                  {
                     "anchorString":"Sign",
                     "anchorXOffset":"350",
                     "anchorYOffset":"-10",
                     "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                     "anchorUnits":"pixels",
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":"1",
                     "recipientId":1,
                     "required":false,
                     "xPosition":"0",
                     "yPosition":"0",
                     "optional":false,
                     "tabLabel":"Signature 1",
                     "locked":false
                  }
               ],
               "dateTabs":null,
               "declineTabs":null,
               "emailTabs":[

               ],
               "envelopeIdTabs":null,
               "fullNameTabs":[
                  {
                     "anchorString":"Sign",
                     "anchorXOffset":"220",
                     "anchorYOffset":"8",
                     "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                     "anchorUnits":"pixels",
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":"1",
                     "recipientId":1,
                     "required":false,
                     "xPosition":"0",
                     "yPosition":"0",
                     "optional":false,
                     "tabLabel":"Signature 1",
                     "locked":false
                  }
               ],
               "listTabs":[

               ],
               "noteTabs":null,
               "numberTabs":[

               ],
               "radioGroupTabs":[

               ],
               "initialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "signHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "anchorString":"Sign",
                     "anchorXOffset":"80",
                     "anchorYOffset":"0",
                     "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":false,
                     "anchorUnits":"pixels",
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":"1",
                     "recipientId":1,
                     "required":false,
                     "scaleValue":1,
                     "xPosition":"0",
                     "yPosition":"0",
                     "optional":false,
                     "tabLabel":"Signature 1",
                     "locked":false
                  }
               ],
               "signerAttachmentTabs":null,
               "ssnTabs":null,
               "textTabs":[

               ],
               "titleTabs":[

               ],
               "zipTabs":null
            }
         }
      ],
      "carbonCopies":[

      ]
   },
   "eventNotification":{
      "useSoapInterface":false,
      "includeCertificateWithSoap":false,
      "url":"valid_accessible_url_endpoint",
      "loggingEnabled":true,
      "envelopeEvents":[
         {
            "includeDocuments":false,
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"completed"
         },
         {
            "includeDocuments":false,
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"sent"
         },
         {
            "includeDocuments":false,
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"delivered"
         }
      ],
      "recipientEvents":[

      ]
   },
   "status":"sent",
   "customFields":null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [connectEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/) api lets you query the Connect logs and failures.

You can also view them using the [DocuSign admin app](https://admindemo.docusign.com/connect). Documentation for the admin app [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect).

If the events were generated successfully and could not be delivered to your Webhook endpoint then they should be listed in the failures section.

Please make your request includes a **https** listener url. DocuSign does not support http listener URL's. Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/)

Comment: Ya, as mentioned in the question, I've checked the Connect logs in the admin app and nothing is showing up there.  Thank you though.

Comment: Can you please share the json from your envelope creation call.

Comment: Ya, I've added it to the original question.  Thanks for taking the time to check it out.  I didn't include the url as it's just an ngrok endpoint and I've verified that it's accessible and working correctly, but I can if that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for providing the JSON. Can you also share an envelopeId that you have created with this JSON.

Comment: Ya.  297ed745-d46f-49dc-8b7c-0d9c9eff2b12

Comment: Looks like you specified a **http** end point (http:/ /695.....) for the listener url. Docusign only supports **HTTPS** endpoints for the webhook notification URLs. Updated my answer with this information.

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but I guess I hadn't.  Thank you very much that solved the issue!